# Get Widget Instance inside Widget

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to access the $instance variable from a custom function I've written inside my Widget, but I keep getting a "variable is undefined" error.

How can I re-create the $instance variable?

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct(
        'cst_twitter_widget',
        __( 'CST Twitter Tweets', 'chicagosuntimes' ),
        array(
            'description' => __( 'Displays Tweets from a given list url.', 'mythemename' ),
        )
    );

    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'cst_twitter_feed_ajaxurl' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_refresh_tweets', array( $this, 'refresh_tweets' ) );

}

/**
 * Set the AJAX URL for the Twitter Feed Widget
 */
public function cst_twitter_feed_ajaxurl() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
<?php
}

/**
 * Display the updated Twitter Feed
 */
public function refresh_tweets() {

    //my custom function, where i'm trying to re-create the $instance and access the values
    $instance = self::$instance;
    echo $instance['cst_twitter_screen_name']; //the variable i'm trying to access
    die();
}

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    //the widget instance
}

public function form( $instance ) {

    //the form
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['cst_twitter_screen_name'] = $new_instance['cst_twitter_screen_name'];

    return $instance;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get widget options using following code

```
$current_widget_options = $this->get_settings();
```

This will return array like `array(instance number => settings)`. Instance number refers to the `$number` of widget.

Example: If your widget instance number is `2` then your required options will be at `$current_widget_options[2]`

**Alternative:**

As `get_settings()` is deprecated, you can use `get_option`. Check following example:

```
  $widget_options_all = get_option($this->option_name);
  $options = $widget_options_all[ $this->number ];
```

Comment: with get_settings() being deprecated, is it still acceptable to use it with plugins / widgets? get_options() is the alternative, but that doesn't return the value.

Comment: Check alternative in the above answer. :-)

Comment: I get an "undefined property" error with the Alternative, but I'll work that out somehow. Marked as correct answer =)

Comment: @stoopkid1 have solution on it? I have similar problem `get_settings();` work fine for one plugin, but when I use two this same plugins...that's not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354968/add-custom-function-to-widget-and-assign-variable